# Javascript/d3 Function for creating new array from an array of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js

Right now I have an array of the form [[1, 2], [3, 4], ...] and need to use an array of the keys [1, 3, ...] and was wondering if there was a javascript or d3 library function that took in the array of arrays and a function, then returned a new array according to the function.  Something like this:

```
var data = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
var keyArray = d3.transformArray(data, function(d) { return d[0]});
// keyArray = [1, 3]
```

So I can avoid looping over the data array again

```
var keyArray = [];
for (i = 0; i < data.length; i += 1) {
    keyArray.push(data[i][0]);
}
// keyArray[1, 3]
```

This seems like a common enough thing to do using d3, but I wasn't sure if there's a specific name for this process of using a specific object and a function to create a new object of the same type.

Comment: `data.map(function(d) { return d[0]; })`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use Array.prototype.map

```
x = [1,2,3].map(function(item){return item+1;});
```

this will result int [2,3,4]

read about this here https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map